# Get values from different tables inside a while loop statement using php

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop

I'm having an issue of retrieving values from two different tables. Here's the code so far:

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM articles");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    $uid=$row['_uid'];

    $result2 = mysqli_query($conn, "SELECT _username FROM users WHERE _id = '$uid' ";
    $num2 = mysqli_num_rows($result2);

    while ($row2 = mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
        $username = $row2['_username'];
    }
    $divtext='<h3>'.$row['_posttype'].'</h3> <h2>'.$username.' </h2>';
}
```

I've been reading that I should preform this while inside a while with multiple query, also found on w3 that you could directly assign a value to a variable directly using:

```
"SELECT _username INTO $username FROM users WHERE  _id = '$uid'  LIMIT 1";
```

But this works in SQL inside myadmin, in a php I can't find how to cast it.
I have also replace the fetch_row for fetch_assoc and still nothing, im struggling for two days already with this.

Comment: You should find somewhere else to read. The first is dangerous code, open to SQL injection, and the second code makes no sense at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could select al the value using a single query

```
SELECT a._uid , a._posttype, u._username 
FROM articles a
INNER JOIN users u on a._uid = u._id
```

..

```
$result = mysqli_query($conn,
  "SELECT a._uid , a._posttype, u._username 
  FROM articles a
  INNER JOIN users u on a._uid = u._id");
$num = mysqli_num_rows($result);

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {

    $divtext='<h3>'.$row['_posttype'].'</h3> <h2>'.$username.' </h2>';

}  

$echo $divtext;
```

Comment: @miken32  .  original code  .. select  all the articles  and for each artilce execute the select for user  .. this execute both in a single query  .. don't need (in this case)  a parameter query  ..

Comment: Thank you @scaisEdge I've just tried it and works. miken32 sorry to be misleading but my autocorrect framed me on this one, that "should" had been a shouldn't, you're absolutely right. 